# ¿LARAVEL: Cómo validar el resultado de una consulta para mostrar un mensaje personalizado en caso de que no hayan registros?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de Laravel y al realizar una consulta almacenada en una variable y enviada a la vista a través del controlador, funciona perfectamente siempre y cuando hayan registros en la base de datos, pero, cuando no hay datos me muestra el siguiente error:
*ErrorException
Undefined variable: subjectTeacher
http://scad.test/home*

Lo que necesito es que cuando la consulta esté vacía, mostrar un mensaje personalizado, algo así como "No hay registros en la base de datos".

Codigo del controlador:

```
    public function index()
{
    $teachers = Teacher::with('subjects')->get();
    foreach ($teachers as $teacher) {
        
        foreach ($teacher->subjects as $subject) {
            $subjectTeacher[] = [
                $teacher->teacher_name => $subject->subject_name
            ];
        }
    }

    return view('home', ['subjectTeacher' => $subjectTeacher]);
}
```

Codigo de la vista:

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
           <tr>
             <th scope="col">Docente</th>
             <th scope="col">Asignatura</th>
             <th scope="col">IH</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @forelse ($subjectTeacher as $teachers => $subjects)
           <tr>
               @forelse ($subjects as $teacherName => $subjectName)
                <td>{{ $teacherName }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subjectName }}</td>
               @empty
                 <p>No hay registros</p>
               @endforelse
                <td>3</td>
          </tr>
               @empty
                 No hay docentes registrados
               @endforelse
       </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué generas un array nuevo de datos en el controlador?

Comment: En ese arreglo almaceno los atributos que necesito mostrar en la vista.

Comment: Lo pregunto por que ese error ni si quiera tiene que ver por que no haya registros, si no tuviera registros tendría que decir algo referido a que tratas de obtener una propiedad de algo que es nulo, considera mandar `$teachers ` a la vista y probar de nuevo

Comment: La cuestión es que cuando hay registros, funciona perfectamente; me sale ese mensaje de error es cuando no hay registros en la base de datos.

Comment: entonces en la vista yo usaría un condicional `if` además de implementar el método `count()` para evaluar si vienen o no resultados en la variable

Comment: Lo voy a probar